# XMPP class not found

Tags: php, xmpp, xmpphp

I want to create a XMPP client with php, I tried this code

```
<?php
include("xmpphp/XMPPHP/xmpp.php");
$conn = new XMPP('192.168.1.62', 5222, 'client', 'pass', 'xmpphp', 'cnx-pc',           $printlog=False, $loglevel=LOGGING_INFO);
$conn->use_encryption = False;
$conn->connect();
$conn->processUntil('session_start');
$conn->message('cnx', 'hi');
$conn->disconnect();
?>
```

but i have this fatal error   Fatal error: Class 'XMPP' not found in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\xmpp1.php on line 3

Any one have an idea about the problem

Comment: What is the absolute path to `xmpp.php`?

Comment: the path is D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\xmpphp\XMPPHP\xmpp.php

Answer (score 1):

The class name is `XMPPHP`, not `XMPP`. Use that, and the error will go away.

Also replace `include` with `require` since you rely on the class to exist.

Comment: I changed it to XMPPHP_XMPP, he accept it but he give me this error

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant LOGGING_INFO - assumed 'LOGGING_INFO' in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\xmpp1.php on line 3
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\xmpphp\XMPPHP\XMLStream.php on line 266

Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\xmpphp\XMPPHP\XMLStream.php on line 266

Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\xmpphp\XMPPHP\XMLStream.php on line 266
Fatal error: Cannot access protected property XMPPHP_XMPP::$use_encryption in D:\EasyPHP-5.3.3.1\www\xmpp1.php on line 4

Comment: then do not access `$use_encryption`.